# How to place all form fields (and the submit button) on a single line?

Tags: css

I`m trying to place all form fields (and the submit button) on a single line, so that the entire form can be read / filled out from left to right.

Here is the code I am working with: [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Abijah/XZXHt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `.form p` `display:inline`. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XZXHt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline` on all the inputs in your form (including the p tag in your case)